# How do i get an item from a list into StorageFile type?

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

How to play a song from playlist when a user clicks on it? Everything file related in UWP is storageFile type. How do I give the media player a stream from a StorageFile?

Answer (score 1):

> How to play a song from playlist when a user clicks on it?

You should define a list to bind to list control(ListView) and then bind the command when the user clicks the Item. And you should write something in the command code to play the song.

> Everything file related in UWP is storageFile type.

Good. You can bind the StorageFile as the property in Item and you can know which item the user clicks on.

> How do I give the media player a stream from a StorageFile?

You should play the song by MediaPlayer that can set the source. If the StorageFile which the user clicks on is `file` and you should use this code to set the source.

```
 MediaPlayerElement.Source = MediaSource.CreateFromStorageFile(file);
 MediaPlayerElement.MediaPlayer.Play();
```

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/media-playback

Comment: Thank you for explaining this, and providing some useful resources.

Comment: @Saihima If this can help you, please click the up button.